# Doxygen: Prevent duplicates due to forward declarations and templates

Tags: c++, doxygen

Doxygen generally handles forward declarations well.  For example,

```
/** \file */

class A;

class B {
    // uses A
};

class A {
    // uses B
};
```

results in

[image]

without duplicating `A`.

But if I make `A` and `B` class templates, then `A` is extracted twice:

```
/** \file */

template<typename T> class A;

template<typename T>
class B {
    // uses A<T>
};

template<typename T>
class A {
    // uses B<T>
};
```

[image]

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 2):

With the versions 1.8.13 - 1.8.18 I can see the behavior as indicated.
With the current doxygen master, i.e. 1.8.19 (0937faf2d168b64f5ccf55c1976bc045d5d12569), this problem looks like to be solved and only `class B<T>` and `class A<T>` are shown.

(It is not yet known / planned when 1.8.19 will be released, the 1.8.18 version has been released on April 12, 2020).